# Can D3 force layout visualize multigraph?

Tags: graph, d3.js, visualization, social-networking, force-layout

It seems that if there exist multiple links between two nodes in D3 force layout, D3 just picks up one and ignores others. Is it possible to visualize multigraph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encode your multigraph trivially as a graph by creating a set of links, where each link is a bundle of the form:

```
{"links": [/* one or more links*/], "source": …, "target": …}
```

You could then run the force-directed layout as per usual to position your nodes. You would then need to represent each bundle appropriately e.g. by drawing parallel lines.

Related: Mike Bostock has used a simple hack to represent [two parallel links between nodes](http://bl.ocks.org/3037015), although this does not easily scale to more links.

Answer (score 7):

So, it turns out that d3 **does** render multiple links between nodes, it's just that it draws them on top of one another.  My approach to addressing this is to draw the links as paths (instead of lines) and to add a different curve to each path.  This means that each link object needs something to differentiate it from others that the same source and target nodes.  My links look like this:

```
links: [
  {"source": 0,"target": 1,"count": 1}, 
  {"source": 1,"target": 2,"count": 1},
  {"source": 1,"target": 3,"count": 1}, 
  {"source": 1,"target": 4,"count": 1},

  // same source and target with greater count
  {"source": 1,"target": 4,"count": 2}, 
  {"source": 1,"target": 4,"count": 3}, 
  {"source": 1,"target": 4,"count": 4}
]
```

And then the path rendering code looks like

```
function tick() {
  link.attr("d", function(d) {
    var x1 = d.source.x,
        y1 = d.source.y,
        x2 = d.target.x,
        y2 = d.target.y,
        dx = x2 - x1,
        dy = y2 - y1,
        // Set dr to 0 for straight edges.
        // Set dr to Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) for a simple curve.
        // Assuming a simple curve, decrease dr to space curves.
        // There's probably a better decay function that spaces things nice and evenly. 
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) - Math.sqrt(300*(d.count-1)); 

   return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + x2 + "," + y2;
  });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bus3S/1/) that demonstrates the approach.